Fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
I'm currently building an android app and I got this error when building it.
Recently, I've shrink my windows partition to add storage to another ubuntu partition and this error came up...
I've tried to uninstall and reinstall OpenJDK 11 but I still have the error. I've tried launching my app with a more recent jdk like 17. It worked but my app is not compatible with jdk 17...
So I need my device to work with jdk 11.
Here are the logs :
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff91e4ee093, pid=18768, tid=16392
#
# JRE version:  (11.0.22+7) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.22+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x1ee093]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: 

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz, 8 cores, 15G,  Windows 11 , 64 bit Build 22621 (10.0.22621.3374)
Time: Mon Apr 29 09:47:07 2024 Paris, Madrid (heure duild 22621 (10.0.22621.3374) elapsed time: 0.022661 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000275891cd000):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=16392, stack(0x000000c069f00000,0x000000c06a000000)]

Stack: [0x000000c069f00000,0x000000c06a000000],  sp=0x000000c069ffeee0,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x1ee093]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1ec1c3]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3826cb]
V  [jvm.dll+0x79f61f]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3f37d7]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3f5cc1]
C  [jli.dll+0x52ef]
C  [ucrtbase.dll+0x29333]
C  [KERNEL32.DLL+0x1257d]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x5aa48]


siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0x0000000000000000


Registers:
RAX=0x0000b6d8e34a7c73, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x000000c069ffeee0, RBP=0x0000000000000000, RSI=0x00000275891cd000, RDI=0x0000000000000000
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x000000c069ffeca0
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00007ff91e8f7f50, R14=0x000000c069fffbf8, R15=0x0000000000000008
RIP=0x00007ff91e4ee093, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010256

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000c069ffeee0)
0x000000c069ffeee0:   00000275890fe390 00007ff91e5eb6c8
0x000000c069ffeef0:   0000000000000008 0000000000000400
0x000000c069ffef00:   0000000000000000 00000275891cd000
0x000000c069ffef10:   0000f194c7160c83 00007ff91e8f7f50
0x000000c069ffef20:   000000c069fff000 000000c069fffbf8
0x000000c069ffef30:   00007ff91e8f7f50 0000000000000000
0x000000c069ffef40:   0000000000000008 0000000000000000
0x000000c069ffef50:   00007ff931490000 00007ff91ebd0488
0x000000c069ffef60:   00007ff91e4ec06a 00007ff9640d1bec
0x000000c069ffef70:   000000c069fff000 0000000000000001
0x000000c069ffef80:   0000b6d8e34a7c73 000000c069fffbf8
0x000000c069ffef90:   00007ff900000000 00007ff91e8f7f50
0x000000c069ffefa0:   00000275891cd000 000000c069fff0c0
0x000000c069ffefb0:   00000275890f70e0 00007ff91e4ec1c3
0x000000c069ffefc0:   00007ff92fe80000 00007ff93149d0f4
0x000000c069ffefd0:   000000c069fff0c0 00000275891cd000 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007ff91e4ee093)
0x00007ff91e4edf93:   f0 ff 15 fe a8 62 00 48 8b cb 41 b1 01 48 2b 8c
0x00007ff91e4edfa3:   24 90 00 00 00 45 33 c0 33 d2 c6 04 31 00 48 8b
0x00007ff91e4edfb3:   ce e8 c7 0b 00 00 42 80 3c 33 3b 4a 8d 3c 33 75
0x00007ff91e4edfc3:   1c 0f 1f 40 00 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 ff c3
0x00007ff91e4edfd3:   ff c5 42 80 3c 33 3b 4a 8d 3c 33 74 f0 49 83 3c
0x00007ff91e4edfe3:   24 00 74 18 48 8b 94 24 98 00 00 00 49 8b cf e8
0x00007ff91e4edff3:   49 44 ed ff 49 8b cc e8 b1 43 ed ff 48 8b 44 24
0x00007ff91e4ee003:   20 48 8d 4c 24 30 4d 89 67 10 49 89 47 18 48 8b
0x00007ff91e4ee013:   44 24 28 49 89 47 20 e8 21 e1 0f 00 44 8b ed 48
0x00007ff91e4ee023:   89 9c 24 90 00 00 00 48 3b 5c 24 38 0f 8c cd fe
0x00007ff91e4ee033:   ff ff 4c 8b 7c 24 40 4c 8b 64 24 48 48 8b 7c 24
0x00007ff91e4ee043:   50 48 8b 74 24 58 48 8b 9c 24 80 00 00 00 48 83
0x00007ff91e4ee053:   c4 60 41 5e 41 5d 5d c3 cc cc cc cc cc 40 53 55
0x00007ff91e4ee063:   56 41 55 48 81 ec b8 00 00 00 48 8b 05 e4 70 8d
0x00007ff91e4ee073:   00 48 33 c4 48 89 84 24 a0 00 00 00 48 8b e9 48
0x00007ff91e4ee083:   c7 c3 ff ff ff ff 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 48 ff c3
0x00007ff91e4ee093:   80 3c 0b 00 75 f7 33 f6 c6 44 24 30 01 40 38 35
0x00007ff91e4ee0a3:   25 a4 90 00 74 17 40 38 35 81 09 90 00 75 0e 33
0x00007ff91e4ee0b3:   d2 48 8d 0d f5 21 6e 00 e8 30 10 1b 00 45 33 ed
0x00007ff91e4ee0c3:   85 db 0f 8e 11 02 00 00 48 89 bc 24 e8 00 00 00
0x00007ff91e4ee0d3:   48 8b fd 48 63 c3 33 db 4c 89 a4 24 f0 00 00 00
0x00007ff91e4ee0e3:   4c 89 b4 24 f8 00 00 00 4c 89 bc 24 b0 00 00 00
0x00007ff91e4ee0f3:   48 89 5c 24 40 48 89 44 24 68 0f 1f 00 0f b6 07
0x00007ff91e4ee103:   84 c0 74 12 3c 3b 74 0e 0f b6 44 2b 01 48 ff c3
0x00007ff91e4ee113:   ff c6 84 c0 75 ee 48 8d 54 24 38 48 c7 44 24 38
0x00007ff91e4ee123:   00 00 00 00 48 8d 4c 24 60 e8 6f df 0f 00 48 8b
0x00007ff91e4ee133:   44 24 38 33 d2 4c 8b b0 78 02 00 00 49 8b 46 18
0x00007ff91e4ee143:   4d 8b 66 10 48 89 44 24 50 49 8b 46 20 48 89 44
0x00007ff91e4ee153:   24 58 49 8b 46 28 48 89 44 24 48 8b c6 41 2b c5
0x00007ff91e4ee163:   48 63 f8 48 8d 4f 01 e8 61 27 4c 00 49 63 d5 4c
0x00007ff91e4ee173:   8b c7 48 03 d5 48 8b c8 4c 8b f8 ff 15 14 a7 62
0x00007ff91e4ee183:   00 48 8b cb 48 2b 4c 24 40 80 7c 24 30 00 42 c6 



---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x00000275890f6c20, length=0, elements={
}

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

=>0x00000275891cd000 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=16392, stack(0x000000c069f00000,0x000000c06a000000)]

Threads with active compile tasks:

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None


[error occurred during error reporting (printing compressed oops mode), id 0xc0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff91eabe297]

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (1 events):
Event: 0.016 Loaded shared library C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot\bin\zip.dll


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff627630000 - 0x00007ff62763e000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe
0x00007ff966990000 - 0x00007ff966ba6000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ff9646c0000 - 0x00007ff964784000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ff964080000 - 0x00007ff964427000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ff964430000 - 0x00007ff964541000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ff9314c0000 - 0x00007ff9314db000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot\bin\VCRUNTIME140.dll
0x00007ff932a00000 - 0x00007ff932a17000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot\bin\jli.dll
0x00007ff964c90000 - 0x00007ff964e3e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ff946340000 - 0x00007ff9465d3000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.22621.3235_none_270f74e173860f98\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ff9645c0000 - 0x00007ff9645e6000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ff964e40000 - 0x00007ff964ee7000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ff964f60000 - 0x00007ff964f89000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ff963f60000 - 0x00007ff964079000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ff964620000 - 0x00007ff9646ba000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ff9650b0000 - 0x00007ff9650e1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007ff932d70000 - 0x00007ff932d7c000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot\bin\vcruntime140_1.dll
0x00007ff91eed0000 - 0x00007ff91ef5d000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot\bin\msvcp140.dll
0x00007ff91e300000 - 0x00007ff91eece000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ff965480000 - 0x00007ff965532000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ff9649e0000 - 0x00007ff964a88000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ff9645f0000 - 0x00007ff964618000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcrypt.dll
0x00007ff964f90000 - 0x00007ff9650a5000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ff966000000 - 0x00007ff966008000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ff94ae90000 - 0x00007ff94ae99000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ff952080000 - 0x00007ff9520b4000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ff95d170000 - 0x00007ff95d17a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ff965640000 - 0x00007ff9656b1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ff962da0000 - 0x00007ff962db8000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ff932b40000 - 0x00007ff932b50000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot\bin\verify.dll
0x00007ff955790000 - 0x00007ff9559c3000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DBGHELP.DLL
0x00007ff9650f0000 - 0x00007ff965478000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ff9667c0000 - 0x00007ff966897000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00007ff950d20000 - 0x00007ff950d52000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbgcore.DLL
0x00007ff963ee0000 - 0x00007ff963f59000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ff931490000 - 0x00007ff9314b8000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot\bin\java.dll
0x00007ff930fb0000 - 0x00007ff930fba000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot\bin\jimage.dll
0x00007ff92fe80000 - 0x00007ff92fe98000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot\bin\zip.dll

dbghelp: loaded successfully - version: 4.0.5 - missing functions: none
symbol engine: initialized successfully - sym options: 0x614 - pdb path: .;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot\bin;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32;C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.22621.3235_none_270f74e173860f98;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot\bin\server

VM Arguments:
java_command: <unknown>
java_class_path (initial): <not set>
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

[Global flags]
     uint G1ConcRefinementThreads                  = 8                                         {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx GCDrainStackTargetSize                   = 64                                        {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t InitialHeapSize                          = 265832128                                 {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 4253314048                                {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ReservedCodeCacheSize                    = 251658240                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
     bool SegmentedCodeCache                       = true                                      {product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseCompressedClassPointers               = true                                 {lp64_product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseCompressedOops                        = true                                 {lp64_product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseG1GC                                  = true                                      {product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseLargePagesIndividualAllocation        = false                                  {pd product} {ergonomic}

Logging:
Log output configuration:
 #0: stdout all=warning uptime,level,tags
 #1: stderr all=off uptime,level,tags

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot
PATH=C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Meld\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;c:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Cursor\resources\app\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\GitHub CLI\;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\php-8.0.30;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\julie\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot\bin;C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;C:\Users\julie\scoop\shims;C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.2\bin;C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.3.2\bin;C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\scripts;C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Users\julie\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\julie\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\julie\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\bin;
USERNAME=julie
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 12, GenuineIntel
TMP=C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Temp
TEMP=C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Temp



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 11 , 64 bit Build 22621 (10.0.22621.3374)
OS uptime: 0 days 0:30 hours

CPU:total 8 (initial active 8) 

Memory: 4k page, system-wide physical 16225M (4466M free)
TotalPageFile size 26977M (AvailPageFile size 12581M)
current process WorkingSet (physical memory assigned to process): 9M, peak: 9M
current process commit charge ("private bytes"): 3M, peak: 3M

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.22+7-LTS) for windows-amd64 JRE (11.0.22+7-LTS), built on Jan 11 2024 20:50:14 by "MicrosoftCorporation" with MS VC++ 16.10 / 16.11 (VS2019)

END.



Are you using windows 11 ?

I've reinstalled OpenJDK11 and restart my computer
It solved my issue
